# Downloading formatted tables into a single Excel workbook using Mathematica

Tags: export, formatting

After uploading 71 tables into Mathematica; I formatted the tables as follows:
[image: Formatted Tables]
Unfortunately; when I attempt to download the formatted tables into a single Excel Workbook using: 
Export["FormatedTables.xlsx", {"Models Table" -> Formatedtable}]
I get the following:
[image: Downloaded formatted tables]
How can I download these tables appropriately?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example with copyable code. Have you tried to find an answer around: [tagged/excel+export](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel+export)?

Comment: also try assigning each table to a variable so you can export each one separately.